# How do I create a simple popup video in Python and close it?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window, toplevel

I have a simple pokemon-battle type project I'm doing for a college but I want to add more visuals to it by adding small 2 sec animations that plays everytime a button is clicked. I thought about using a toplevel window which plays a video using tkvideo. It works, but I can't figure out how to close it after 2 secs OR after it loops the video once.

Can anyone offer suggestions to a newbie? P.S. I used Toplevel because there is already a main root window where the player can click buttons.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkvideo import tkvideo

window = tkinter.Toplevel()
window.title("Video PLayer")

lblVideo = Label(window)
lblVideo.pack()

player = tkvideo("Hero_Slash_Attack_Animation.mp4", lblVideo, loop=1, size=(500,500),)

player.play()

window.mainloop()
```

The code up above is what I used to play a secondary video window but. But I can't figure out how to close that specific top level. I tried w.destroy() but it didn't remove it. Instead, the video just keeps looping and staying.

Comment: Add `window.after(2000, window.destroy)` just before the `player.play`. For more info read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/11106801). Also you don't need to call `.mainloop()` on `tk.Toplevel`s.

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: `window.destroy()` should close the video window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tkVideoPlayer`](https://pypi.org/project/tkvideoplayer/) instead of [`tkvideo`](https://pypi.org/project/tkVideo/). Here is a link to the [*documentation*](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/master/Documentation.md).

###### For example:

```python
import tkinter as tk
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo

root = tk.Tk()

def close_video(win):
    if win.winfo_exists():
        win.destroy()

def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.lift()

    player = TkinterVideo(master=window, scaled=True)
    player.load(r"video.mp4")
    player.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    window.after(2000, close_video, window) # close win after 2 sec
    player.bind("<<Ended>>", lambda event: close_video(window)) # close the win if video ended

    player.play() # play the video

tk.Button(root, text="Show Video", command=create_window).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

- Created a function for closing the window.
- Bound the event of video ended to that function
- Scheduled the window to close 2 seconds after the window is launched.

Comment: It seems like OP is using [`tkvideo`](https://pypi.org/project/tkVideo/) instead of the [`tkvideoplayer`](https://pypi.org/project/tkvideoplayer/) that your code uses. Also OP makes the video loop.

Comment: @TheLizzard Yes, but OP requested to close the window after the video is played once or after two seconds.. I couldn't find the video ended event in `tkvideo` so i suggested an alternative.

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I'm currently trying your method and it works with what I have. Just a small question, the popup video is very small for some reason, how would I make a fixed resolution size for my video? Would I use .resize() ?

Comment: Hey, I read in the documentation that you can use `player.set_size`. But I think it would be easier to use `window.geometry`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the virtual event feature of `tkvideoplayer` module mentioned in other answer using `tkvideo` module by creating a custom class inherited from `tkvideo` and overload the class method `load()`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkvideo import tkvideo as orig_tkvideo

# custom class inherits from tkvideo
class tkvideo(orig_tkvideo):
    # overload load() method
    def load(self, *args):
        try:
            super().load(*args)
            # vidoe ended, generate virtual event "<<End>>" to container
            self.label.event_generate("<<End>>")
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)  # or pass

window = tk.Toplevel()
window.title("Video PLayer")
window.transient(window.master)

lblVideo = tk.Label(window)
lblVideo.pack()
# close window upon receiving virtual event "<<End>>"
lblVideo.bind("<<End>>", lambda e: window.destroy())

player = tkvideo("_output.mp4", lblVideo, loop=0, size=(500, 500))
player.play()

# close window after 2 seconds
lblVideo.after(2000, window.destroy)

window.mainloop()
```